# postgresql.conf file on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql-10

I am setting up an application on AWS. In my application, I use postgresql database. My purpose is to configure database to make logs look different from default. Do I have complete access to postgresql.conf file( As I have for example on Ubuntu OS ) on AWS or do they have some restrictions about id?

Answer (score 0):

You have no access to `postgresql.conf` on RDS.

What you *do* have is the ability to change parameters via [parameter groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html). The specific parameters that you can change are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Parameters). I don't see `log_line_prefix` in that list, so you're probably out of luck if that's what you're looking to configure.